# MySQL Query to populate 2 Relational combo php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, combobox

I am having 2 combo country and Network.
I have to populate combo Network value on the basis of Country selected in Combo Country.
Where in mysql, network is "Name" and Countries list are present to corresponding 
network as "Country".

```
$query = "SELECT Name FROM resource_network ORDER BY Name ASC;".
"WHERE resource_network.Country = ***** " ;
```

i need help to get the value of *****, i mean how i should store the selected value from combo Country and display in my query.

mysql (resource_network) hold the value of network as "Name" and Country as "Country"
Thanks

***Edit for Complete code:***

Query the available Network Operators from the database.
   * @return The list of Network Operators XML formatted for a DHTMLX combo box.And then
 Sends XML header in response to HTTP request.

```
function queryNetwork()
{    
 $country = $_REQUEST["country"];
$mask = $_REQUEST["mask"];

/* Connect to the Database. */
global $MySQL_Server, $MySQL_User, $MySQL_PWD, $MySQL_DB;
$dbLink = connectMySqlAndSelectDb($MySQL_Server, $MySQL_User, $MySQL_PWD, $MySQL_DB);

if(!$dbLink)
  return false;

{
    $query = "SELECT Name FROM resource_network ORDER BY Name ASC;".
"WHERE resource_network.Country = ***** " ;
    $result = mysql_query($query, $dbLink) or die(mysql_error());
    $xml = "<complete>\n";

}
$result = mysql_query($query, $dbLink) or die(mysql_error());
$xml = "<complete>\n";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $xml .= "<option value=\"".$row["Name"]."\" text=\"".$row["Name"]."\"/>\n";

}
$xml .= "</complete>\n";
mysql_close($dbLink);
sendHttpHeadersXml();
echo $xml;
return true;
```

Comment: You submit the form / pass the selected value via AJAX ? Please clarify.